# multiple variables in same for loop (Jinja2, Yaml)

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have a list in yaml file

```
users:
  name:
    - abc
    - pqr
  age:
    - 10
    - 12
```

I want to iterate over above values in jinja2 template. 
Member in `name` is associated with member in `age` of same index. So I want to iterate over both in single line only.

```
{% for n in users['name'] and for a in users['age'] %}
    {{ n }}
    {{ a }}
{% endfor %}
```

For loop in this code isn't working. 
I checked official documentation but I could not find any example like this. 
Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The template below

```
{% for item in users.name|zip(users.age)|list %}
    {{ item.0 }}
    {{ item.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

gives:

```
$ cat test.txt 
    abc
    10
    pqr
    12
```